# I am not able to run fresh java web application project in netbeans IDE 7.3

Tags: java, web-applications, netbeans-7.3

In netbeans IDE 7.3,I create Java web application.I didn't add anything.Just a simple project.
I am using glassfish server.Then I cleaned and built it.When I click on Run,

I get output as "**Host Required In Request**

**Description: Your browser did not send a hostname as part of the requested url. The configuration of this proxy requires a hostname to be sent as part of the url**" in chrome browser.

I also get this output while running same project : **Cycle Detected
Description: Your request is prohibited because it would cause a cycle.**

I am not getting why this errors are coming.Because earlier when I used to create any new fresh project, I can see contents of index.jsp page in browser.

Comment: How do you run this NetBeans project? Is it a HTML 5 project? Do you use any of the Chrome remote control features of NetBeans?

Comment: After right clicking on project,we get option for Run.I do it in that way.

Comment: are you sure you did not add any filter? what if you run the same code under tomcat - cut and paste in a new project..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to open it in Firefox and see if it works.  If you have redirects, Chrome complains.

Comment: @ Indu Devanath: successfully run on Firefox.but not on IE 10 and chrome.Thanx